# scrollViewDidScroll is called without touching

Tags: ios, scrollview, tableview

When I came into my ViewController and the method `scrollViewDidScroll` is always called before I touch it even not drag it.

Comment: Are you rotating your device or something? Because the orientation method gets called when orientation changes...

Comment: I don't rotate anything.

Comment: Is there UITableView embedded within UIVIEwController?

Comment: Yes I insert a UITableView using storyboard within UIViewController

Answer (score 1):

The problem is causing by the tableView, it is a subclass of `UISCrolView` so this as well called the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate . `[self.tableView reloadData];`

Comment: how can I deal with it?

Comment: in that delegate method, check the scrollView is belongs to what and do remaining stuff

Answer (score -1):

If you want to distinguish the events from your tableview and your scrollview, you could implement a check

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if([scrollView isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
        // it's the tableview
    } else {
        //it's the scrollview
    }
}
```